# Query to calculate the number of different products sold to a certain customer

Tags: mysql, sql

Say there is an SQL table

```
SHIPMENTS(ProductNumber, ClientNumber, Quantity)
(1,1,4)
(2,5,2)
(1,1,2)
(4,1,5)
(2,5,3)
```

In the example above we notice that client #1 has made three purchases (twice the same product). Hence, the answer should be 2 since we're looking for the number of DIFFERENT products purchased by that client.

Applying this query

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM SHIPMENTS
WHERE ClientNumber = 1;
```

Will understandably give 3 as a result. And I can't think of the solution as to how to calculate only for the different products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT ProductNumber)
FROM SHIPMENTS
WHERE ClientNumber = 1;
```

This should do the trick. Adding DISTINCT takes every unique value once:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: Yeah the syntax section on that link shows a nice example.  I was going to link the same page lol.

Comment: @MikeS great minds think alike i guess ;p site has a nice executable example as well.

Comment: xD i wouldn't call myself that, but no problem.Don't forget to mark it as solved if it's working as you expect it to be, and good luck on your project!